# Hitting html body limit of 32000 characters with only one Email

Tags: email, error, html, limits

Good Morning,
Like the title says, I do not understand why I'm hitting the charathicter Limit, I used a character counter online, copy and pasted my Email and it only returned ~1400 characters.
The only reason I think this might be happening is because of an Image that is being inserted on the email body.

Let me know please if you know the reason for this to happen.

[image]

Comment: Hey, How are you creating the email? If you are copying and pasting it the image will probably be pushing the character count up

Comment: Try to count symbols in the already generated and received email.

Comment: From what I know the person writing the Email is copying it from outlook, does that change anything?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you're using a character count on the plain text. The underlying HTML formatting characters all count toward the 32,000 maximum.

Likewise, the fact that this is copied directly from an external place (outlook) means it could have other formatting attached to it being counted. You could have the user paste into a text-only editor (notepad) and then re-paste into Salesforce to see if it goes under the limit.

The help doc below mentions other ways of getting around this if it's a chronic issue or you have a use case where you might need more characters.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334948&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using email templates? If yes it could be useful to take a look at html inside it. You are hitting the limit with the html body I don't think it is usefull to count the rendered characters.

Comment: This is not an Email template, but the person who has written this email has copied it from outlook, does that help?